# Hakyll build failing using Stack

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack, hakyll

When building [Hakyll](https://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/) using Stack [as suggested](https://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/tutorials/01-installation.html), I do something like this (pinning the resolver version for immutability):

```
$ stack --resolver lts-6.6 install hakyll
```

But what I get is:

```
Progress: 10/23
--  While building package x509-1.6.3 using:
      /home/nick/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux/setup-Simple-Cabal-1.22.5.0-ghc-7.10.3 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0 configure --with-ghc=/home/nick/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-7.10.3/bin/ghc --with-ghc-pkg=/home/nick/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-7.10.3/bin/ghc-pkg --user --package-db=clear --package-db=global --package-db=/home/nick/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-6.7/7.10.3/pkgdb --libdir=/home/nick/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-6.7/7.10.3/lib --bindir=/home/nick/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-6.7/7.10.3/bin --datadir=/home/nick/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-6.7/7.10.3/share --libexecdir=/home/nick/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-6.7/7.10.3/libexec --sysconfdir=/home/nick/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-6.7/7.10.3/etc --docdir=/home/nick/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-6.7/7.10.3/doc/x509-1.6.3 --htmldir=/home/nick/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-6.7/7.10.3/doc/x509-1.6.3 --haddockdir=/home/nick/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-6.7/7.10.3/doc/x509-1.6.3 --dependency=asn1-encoding=asn1-encoding-0.9.4-52d17dc2a2e779a5ef2b648ff3af0b8d --dependency=asn1-parse=asn1-parse-0.9.4-43faa79aaa0849b68c778a71952dc386 --dependency=asn1-types=asn1-types-0.3.2-29bde644dfae66857755e962eab5b971 --dependency=base=base-4.8.2.0-0d6d1084fbc041e1cded9228e80e264d --dependency=bytestring=bytestring-0.10.6.0-9a873bcf33d6ce2fd2698ce69e2c1c66 --dependency=containers=containers-0.5.6.2-59326c33e30ec8f6afd574cbac625bbb --dependency=cryptonite=cryptonite-0.15-34cd3a38b66fe576d3e80f28bfa0826d --dependency=hourglass=hourglass-0.2.10-337cca0f9d281b8b30d82ffb2a5abd50 --dependency=memory=memory-0.13-039b91f332a8ac781f93bf90ac1b3d77 --dependency=mtl=mtl-2.2.1-3af90341e75ee52dfc4e3143b4e5d219 --dependency=pem=pem-0.2.2-5f6df2ca3b7f68abc9010881cb82b5dd
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
    Logs have been written to: /home/nick/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/logs/x509-1.6.3.log

    Configuring x509-1.6.3...
    setup-Simple-Cabal-1.22.5.0-ghc-7.10.3: The following installed packages are
    broken because other packages they depend on are missing. These broken
    packages must be rebuilt before they can be used.
    package pem-0.2.2 is broken due to missing package
    base64-bytestring-1.0.0.1-4aa13e7ac7c5b00cc0cd642708d4e148,
    bytestring-0.10.6.0-c60f4c543b22c7f7293a06ae48820437
```

I've tried various other `lts-*` resolvers but no luck there either, and can't really work out what's needed to fix the build issue... especially being a bit of a newbie here... Any ideas, please?

Comment: What is your `stack` version ? Also, why don't you just try `stack install hakyll` (although your command should also work).

Comment: Hi. This is Stack `1.1.2`, and I did try that - it's just to indicate what resolver I'm using really.

Comment: This seems strange. Can you nuke your `~/.stack` and try again ?

Comment: @sibi that worked! No idea why... but thanks! If you want to make it an answer I can accept (though am interested what was happening still)

Comment: Flagging to close since it doesn't seem reproducible any ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you have corrupted packages in your `~/.stack`.

So nuking `~/.stack` and trying to install again would be a good check to see if that is the case.